# Save temporary Ajax parameters in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-applications

I am developing a heavily scripted Web application and am now doing some Error handling. But to do that, I need a way to access the AJAX parameters that were given to jQuery for that specific AJAX Request. I haven't found anything on it at jquery.com so I am asking you folks if you have any idea how to accomplish that.

Here is an example of how I want to do that codewise:

```
function add_recording(filename) {
    updateCounter('addRecording','up');
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/cgi-bin/apps/ajax/Storyboard',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            sid: sid,
            story: story,
            screen_id: screen_id,
            mode: 'add_record',
            file_name: filename
        },
        success: function(json) {
            updateCounter('addRecording','down');
            id = json[0].id;
            create_record(id, 1, 1, json);
        },
        error: function() {
            updateCounter('addRecording','error',hereBeData);
        }
    })
}
```

hereBeData would be the needed data (like the url, type, dataType and the actual data).

updateCounter is a function which updates the Status Area with new info. It's also the area where the User is notified of an Error and where a Dismiss and Retry Button would be generated, based on the Info that was gathered in hereBeData.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of calling `complete()` `success()` or `error()` - `this` will equal the object passed to $.ajax()  although the values for URL and data will not always be exactly the same - it will convert paramerters and edit the object around a bit.  You can add a custom key to the object to remember your stuff though:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/',
  data: {test:'test'},
  // we make a little 'extra copy' here in case we need it later in an event
  remember: {url:'/', data:{test:'test'}},

  error: function() {
    alert(this.remember.data.test + ': error');
  },
  success: function() {
    alert(this.remember.data.test + ': success');
  },
  complete: function() {
    alert(this.remember.data.url + ': complete');
  }
});
```

Of course - since you are setting this data originally from some source - you could rely on the variable scoping to keep it around for you:

```
$("someelement").click(function() {
   var theURL = $(this).attr('href');
   var theData = { text: $(this).text(); }
   $.ajax({ 
     url: theUrl,
     data: theData,
     error: function() {
       alert('There was an error loading '+theURL);
     } 
   });

   // but look out for situations like this: 
   theURL = 'something else';
});
```

Comment: yes - of course it is - his particular case was only asking about the error event, but regardless of which one is being called (which could be success/error and then complete - `this` still points to the object parameter of the ajax function.

Comment: I can see where this is going. So no matter how it is done, I need to store it explicitly for my purpose.

Comment: Yeah - the "url" in that example gets rewritten to "/?test=test" and "data" is set to null, if it were a POST the URL would still be "/" and the data becomes "test=test" - so either deconstruct from there, or the (much easier) recommendation - create a key that jquery wont mess with and set the important information there.  Or just leave it around in a variable in the parent function.

Comment: That's the way I'm gonna do it. I hoped for a more elegant solution but this works out just as good.

Answer (score 1):

Check out what parameters you can get in the [callback for error](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options).

```
function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  // typically only one of textStatus or errorThrown 
  // will have info
  this; // the options for this ajax request
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ajax [complete event](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/ajaxComplete#callback) which passes you the ajaxOptions that were used for the request. The complete fires for both a successful and failed request.

```
complete : function (event, XMLHttpRequest, ajaxOptions) {
   //store ajaxOptions here
   //1 way is to use the .data on the body for example
   $('body').data('myLastAjaxRequest', ajaxOptions);
}
```

You can then retireve the options using

```
var ajaxOptions = $('body').data('myLastAjaxRequest');
```

Comment: There is a LOT of information in there (url and type is all there) but I can't find my data

Comment: It should all be in ajaxOptions.data
I have tested and can confirm this